# The constructor Client(String, String, String, String, String) is undefined

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I am supposed to simulate a management and billing application for a phone company. I created some classes, and one object for each class, but I get this error: "The constructor Client(String, String, String, String, String) is undefined"
Here are the relevant classes:

```
public class CreateUsers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client("user1", "user", "user", "Client", "12345678");
        Admin admin = new Admin("user2", "user", "user", "Admin");
        Seller seller = new Seller("user3", "user", "user", "Seller");
    }
}
```

```
public class Client extends Users {
       String AFM;
       public Client(String u, String n, String s, String p, String i){
        this.AFM = i;
        this.username = u;
        this.name = n;
        this.surname = s;
        this.property= p;
        UsersCount++;
        } 
       public void ViewBill() 
       {
          System.out.println("The bill"); 
       }
       public void ViewHistory() 
       {
          System.out.println("The history"); 
       }
       public void PayBill() 
       {
          System.out.println("Bill payment"); 
       }

    public String getAFM() {
        return AFM;
    }
}
```

```
public class Admin extends Users
{
    public Admin() {
        UsersCount++;
    }
    public void CreateSeller() 
    {
        System.out.println("Seller was created!");
    }
    public void DeleteSeller() 
    {
        System.out.println("Seller was deleted!");
    }
    public void CreateUser() 
    {
        System.out.println("User was created!");
    }
    public void DeleteUser() 
    {
        System.out.println("User was deleted!");
    }
    public void CreateNewProgram() 
    {
        System.out.println("A new program was created!");
    }
}
```

```
public class Seller extends Users 
{
    int salary;
    String shift;
    String pt_or_ft;
    public void NewCustomer()
    {
        System.out.println("Customer was created!");
    }
    public void IssueBill()
    {
        System.out.println("Bill was issued!");
    }
    public void ChangeProgram()
    {
        System.out.println("Program was changed!");
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String getShift() {
        return shift;
    }
    public void setShift(String shift) {
        this.shift = shift;
    }
    public String getPt_or_ft() {
        return pt_or_ft;
    }
    public void setPt_or_ft(String pt_or_ft) {
        this.pt_or_ft = pt_or_ft;
    }
    public Seller() {
        UsersCount++;
    }
}
```

```
public class Users
{
    String username;
    String name;
    String surname;
    String property;
    static int UsersCount = 0;

    static void register()
    {
        System.out.println("User registerd!");
    }

    static void login()
    {
        System.out.println("Login succesful!");
    }

    static void logout()
    {
        System.out.println("Logout succesful!");
    }
    public String getUserame()
    {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String newUsername) 
    {
        this.username = newUsername;
    }
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String newName) 
    {
        this.name = newName;
    }
    public String getSurname() 
    {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String newSurname) 
    {
        this.surname = newSurname;
    }
    public String getProperty() 
    {
        return property;
    }
    public void setProperty(String newProperty) 
    {
        this.property = newProperty;
    }
    public Users() {}
}
```

I am getting these errors in the CreateUsers class, in the lines where I declared the objects "admin" and "seller".

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: First of all please create constructor for Admin and Seller class.

Comment: `Admin` and `Seller` do not have a constructor with 5 parameters. Either remove the 5 arguments in your `new Admin/Seller()` calls or add an constructor with such 5 arguments.

Comment: @Progman already stated and also have imported correct client class ?

Comment: It's usually good practice to put your constructors before your methods, to make them easily findable. The one problem I see is that you call Admin and Seller with 4-string constructors, but no such constructors are defined.

Comment: Please save all your source codes files and compile all source files again, then [edit] your question to include the current error message you get. Your current error message from the question doesn't fit the source code you have shown. Also verify that the source code you shown is the current source code you have.

Comment: I created constructors for Admin and Seller. Now I'm getting the warning "The value of the local variable client/admin/seller is not used" in the declaration of all 3 objects, but the errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

instead of having the **public static void main(String[] args) {}**
you can have like a public fuction with a method that will include all your variables as parameters for example this is how I would have done it.

```
public class CreateUsers {
    public ClientData(String Client, String Admin, String) {
        Client client = new Client("user1", "user", "user", "Client", "12345678");
        Admin admin = new Admin("user2", "user", "user", "Admin");
        Seller seller = new Seller("user3", "user", "user", "Seller");
    }
}
```